# Jhipster blueprint can't override the entire priority

Tags: javascript, jhipster, yeoman, jhipster-blueprint

I want to customize [addEntityToMenu](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/8ce426f707e94eb3caadc067dd4ede15023da209/generators/client/needle-api/needle-client-react.cjs#L30) function. I created a blueprint with entities-client as sub-generator then override POST_WRITING_PRIORITY with my custom functions.

My purpose is creating a custom MenuItem and then add it to `entities/Menu.tsx`, which uses `jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-menu` to generate link entity items.

```js
//generate.mjs
const files = import('myCustom.cjs');
//...
  get [POST_WRITING_PRIORITY]() {
    return {
      async addToMenu() {
        if (this.skipClient) return undefined;
        return (await files).addToMenu.call(this);
      }
    };
  }
```

the origin `addToMenu` function will generate a React component [like this](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/8ce426f707e94eb3caadc067dd4ede15023da209/generators/client/needle-api/needle-client-react.cjs#L35)

my custom function will generate an object like:

```
{"label":"<a href=\"/movie\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">\nMovie\n</a>","key":"movie"},
```

I also custom the `Menu.tsx` to accept that result.

But this is the result when I run

```
jhipster jdl app.jdl --blueprints generator-jhipster-my-custom
```

```
<MenuItem icon="asterisk" to="/movie">
<Translate contentKey="global.menu.entities.movie" />
</MenuItem>
{"label":<ahref=\"/movie\"target=\"_blank\"rel=\"noreferrer\">\nMovie\n</a>","key":"movie"},
```

Seem like the `addEntitiesToMenu` is run twice. One from `generator-jhipster` and one from `generator-jhipster-my-custom`. But the problem is I overridden it. I debugged and research a lot but don't know why. What's wrong? Thanks!

Additional: [all of my code](https://github.com/dunfe/jhipster-antd-entity/tree/custom-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implemented blueprint is a [side-by-side blueprint](https://github.com/dunfe/jhipster-antd-entity/blob/65a3fd9f82d873cf53b2d8b5ae3cb559e4f99402/generators/client/generator.mjs#L35).

[Side-by-side blueprints](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/extending-and-customizing/#side-by-side-blueprint) does not change the original blueprint behavior. You can write new file, change or remove generated files, but you cannot make the original generator don't generate those files.

To change the behavior (skip some parts), you need to implement a normal  blueprint (remove sbsBlueprint property) and inherit every parts you need. Documentation https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/.